# onsubmit: jQuery alert if field is empty

Tags: jquery, if-statement

On my website, I have a button that says "GET A FREE CONSULTATION" and next to the button is an email field. When the user types in their email and then presses the button, their email is submitted to a google spreadsheet, and a popup appears with more information.

How can I add jQuery code into the "onsubmit" part of the  tag that says: If the email field contains an email address, submit the form and show the popup. Otherwise ("else"), display an alert box that says "Please enter your email address."

Here's what my code looks like now:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/xxxxx/formResponse" method="POST" id="ss-form-landing" onsubmit="$('.landing-button').click();return true;" target="hidden_iframe">

<input type="text" name="entry.xxx" value="" id="entry_2005747986" class="landing-pg-email-field" placeholder="Enter email address"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="GET A FREE &#x00A; CONSULTATION" class="landing-pg-button">
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $form = $('#ss-form-landing'), $field = $form.find('input.landing-pg-email-field');

    $form.submit(function(){
        if($.trim($field.val()) == ''){
            alert('enter a email id');
            return false;
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P8pL3/)

Comment: Thanks!  That does work to show the alert when the email field is empty... however, after I close the alert box, my regular popup still appears. How do I make it so that only the alert box appears and the regular popup is prevented from appearing?  (My regular popup was created using the Simp Modal Popup plugin for Wordpress, and it is set to open when '.landing-button' is clicked.)